# Посчитать размер файла в байтах на shell

Tags: linux, shell

Основная задача - узнать размер файла. 
Изначально в проекте пользовался du -b file.txt.
Проект переехал на BusyBox. Теперь у команды du нет опции -b.
Каким образом еще можно посчитать размер файла в байтах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для получения подробной информации о файлах надо использовать команду `stat`:

```
stat имя-файла -c %s
```

Для получения информации в том же виде, как выдает `du -b` т.е. с именем файла после размера, можно использовать формат `-c "%s %n"`